# SOAP Header Name space

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

Service expecting

```
POST /ADNHContact.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.xxx-xxx.co.uk/ADNIntegration/SaveGrantApplication"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <Action xmlns="http://www.xxx-xxx.co.uk/ADNIntegration/" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <SaveGrantApplication xmlns="http://www.xxx-xxx.co.uk/ADNIntegration/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

C# Code for service

```
public class Action : SoapHeader
{
    string somestring;

}

[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.xxx-xxx.co.uk/Integration/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class ADNHContact : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public Action AppHeader;

    [SoapHeader("AppHeader")]
    [WebMethod(Description = "AppHeader  testing")]
    public Compny[] SaveApplication()
    {

            Compny[] comp = new Compny[] {
            new Compny()
            { companyID="C123",companyName="ddd"}

            };
            return comp;

    }
```

But I want to change the header to this.

```
    <soap:Header>
             <Action xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">
http://www.xxx-xxx.co.uk/ADNIntegration/SaveGrantApplication</Action>
        </soap:Header>
```

Comment: thanks need to change in to xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none"

Comment: basically <Action xmlns="http://www.xxx-xxx.co.uk/ADNIntegration/" /> need to change <Action xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">
http://www.xxx-xxx.co.uk/ADNIntegration/SaveGrantApplication</Action>